# jQuery UI: how to run evaluation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, conditional-statements

I want to add 'Year' or Years' to the end of a string depending on the string.
Like this:

```
$("#selector").val(conditional_value_here);
```

Using jQuery UI I have a slider that manipulates a value:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 25,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.value + ' Year' + function(){return (ui.value == 1) ? '' : 's';} );
    }
  });

// and again I want to do the same for the initialization of the value:
$("#amount_3").val($("#slider_3").slider("value") + ' Jahr' + function(){return ($("#slider_3").slider("value") == 1) ? '' : 's';});
```

This does not work. What is the correct way to to this?

Comment: I doubt many people will bother answering this since you marked it as a community wiki and they will not get reputation for anything they post.

Comment: thanks for the info, my mistake.. can't undo it, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

As Reigel said, you can just use the ternary operator `? :` without requiring the function.

```
condition ? x : y;
```

If `condition` is true, then `x` is returned, otherwise `y` is returned. When using it, just make sure to use parentheses liberally.

```
str = "This is " + numDays + numDays == 1 ? " day" : " days" + " old";

// no matter the value of numDays, the above always evaluates to " day"
// it is equivalent to:

str = ("This is " + numDays + numDays == 1) ? (" day") : (" days" + " old");

// instead, this is probably what was wanted:

str = "This is " + numDays + (numDays == 1 ? " day" : " days") + " old";
```

Alternatively, if you had a really *really* ***really*** good reason to do something like what you tried in your example, you could make it work like this:

```
$("#amount").val(
    ui.value + ' Year' + (function(){return (ui.value == 1) ? '' : 's';})()
);
```

...but if I saw something like that in production, I'd be forced to hunt you down with a large axe.

Comment: thanks, but could you explain how does this work:

    str = "This is " + numDays + (numDays ? " day" : " days") + " old";


I mean, where's the condition? Since there is no comparative operator involved will the var numDays not evaluate to TRUE unless it's zero? so that both 1 and 3 will result in the strings '1 days' and '3 days' respectively?

Answer (score 0):

just

```
$("#amount").val(ui.value + ' Year' + (ui.value == 1) ? '' : 's');
```

Comment: don't forget precedence. `ui.value + ' Year' + (ui.value == 1)` will always be true.